# In Visual Studio 2019 how do you specify the framework for a class project to 4.5?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a mod for Stardew Valley, and it says that the class frameworks should be 4.5 to match the framework that Stardew Valley targets.

When I create .net projects I can specify that, but when I am creating the class framework it only goes up to 2.1.

Am I missing something stupid here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the project you have to target a "Window desktop" template that uses the .NET Framework (not net standard or net core) and select the version from the bottom of the form.

[image]